# Why can't R read the text file

Tags: r, text-mining

Try to get R read my text file and do a text mining, but following the steps it's not working, don't know what's wrong. Someone plz help me

```
library(tm)
setwd("E://")
path="E:/KEYWORDS"
text<-readLines("KEYWORDS.txt")
corpus<- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
corpus<- tm_map(corpus,tolower)
corpus<- tm_map(corpus,removePunctuation)
corpus<-tm_map(corpus,stripWhitespace)
corpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(corpus))
tdm =TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,PlainTextDocument)
findFreTerms(tdm,lowfreq=2)
```

And it shows:

```
Warning message:
In tm_map.SimpleCorpus(corpus, removePunctuation) :
transformation drops documents
tdm =TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,PlainTextDocument)
Error: is.list(control) is not TRUE
```

And if you do this

```
str(readLines("KEYWORDS.txt"))
paste(str(readLines("KEYWORDS.txt")),collapse=" ")
text<-paste(str(readLines("KEYWORDS.txt")),collapse=" ")
gsub(pattern="//W", replace="  ", text)
text<-gsub(pattern="//W",replace=" ",text)
gsub(pattern="//d", replace=" ", text)
text<-gsub(pattern="//d", replace=" ", text1)
tolower(text)
text<-tolower(text)
text
```

It shows the text is null or contains 0 characters
why?

Comment: Your second problem, after you say "And if you do this", is because `str` is designed to show you the output, and does not return anything, as documented in `help(str)`. If you try one line at a time you'll see this happens at line 3 and your other lines are doing nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tdm =TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,PlainTextDocument)
Error: is.list(control) is not TRUE
```

that's because you've given the second parameter to `TermDocumentMatrix` as `PlainTextDocument` rather than a list of control arguments. Read the documentation for TermDocumentMatrix to see what is a valid set of control arguments.

You say you are doing this by "following the steps" but you should understand the steps first.

Comment: Thanks, I tried another way: cname <- file.path("E:", "KEYWORDS")
cname
dir(cname)
library(tm)
text <- Corpus(DirSource(cname))
summary(text)
text <- tm_map(text, removePunctuation)
text <- tm_map(text, tolower)
text <- tm_map(text, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
text <- tm_map(text, PlainTextDocument)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(text)
dtm
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(text)
tdm
And then it works

Comment: But if keep the original way to get R read the text,what can I do?=-=

Comment: That's a separate question - tidy it up and make a new question.